# Error 404 resource not found in postman for webapi image in azure

Tags: azure, docker, docker-container, azure-container-service

I have created two WEBAPI project(one for HTTPGET and another one for HTTPPOST) and I have deployed two docker images for those webapi in azure container.
While accessing that image via ip and port which have been provided by azure, i am getting 404 resource not found error for HTTPPOST container image but i am able to access other one.

Could anyone help me here?